# stop thread on exiting app

Tags: android, multithreading, session

i need to stop/interrupt a thread made by myself when exiting my app. how can i do this?
it should be albe to click on any activity the home button and it should end the thread.

basically the thread i created acts as a session and when one logsout or his session time expires or the app closes then i need to stop the thread. i've managed that for the first 2 cases, but i'm not ble to do it for the third case. infact once i go out of the app in my logCat i can see the thread and when it naturally dies i get a toast notification (which i clearly dont want). tahnks!

Comment: What exactly is that thread doing and why does it need to stop?

Comment: Heck, why is it a thread in the first place? If I had a developer say he was going to use a thread that "acts as a session", I might be inclined to fire him immediately.

Comment: @CommonsWare because the webservice im using doesnt give me a session cookie with a determined time. how else would i do it?

Comment: "how else would i do it" -- you would do it however you would from a Web app, which would not involve forking a thread. For example, you might use a `boolean` to keep track of whether you are logged in or not, or you might use a `Calendar` object to represent when you think the user's session will no longer be valid.

Comment: the calendar example seems compatible with my requirements (because im interested in the session time). could u please show me and example/tutorial? would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure I really understood what you want but you should check the methods relative to an activity lifecycle :

=> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Look for

```
onPause()
onResume()
onStop()
```

Then, on each event you do whatever you want with the thread like stopping it

Comment: Correcting myself :p I'd go with onPause + onStop

Answer (score 1):

First of all, on hitting home the application is not really exited due to Android's multitasking system. When home is hit the application is paused, so the onPaused method is called. When you hit back, or if the device decides it needs more memory, the application will be killed and onDestroed is called (there are step in between there). See the android lifecycle.[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

If I were you would put the thread stop in the onDestroyed method as that is where the application needs to be created again, but all of them are called when destroyed.

However, in your case it seems that you want something that acts more like a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). A service is like an activity, but runs in the background, with no UI. Like how pandora plays music without the app being up. With a service you can start it some from any of your activities and end it when any activity is killed (onStop or on Destroy), you could do a semaphore like solution where when all activities using it are killed, it kills itself. And when any activity using it starts(onCreate or onStart), it starts the service. Then you can access the service via static members or keep an instance of it in each activity,

Comment: very interesting. would i also be able to interact with the service? because i need the to check the session time and based on that close the session/keep the session open.

Comment: Yeah, if I have anything that needs to be accessible as a public static variable so I just hit TimerSaverService.currentData when I know that data exists.  You can also attach a listener from the current activity to have the service call methods in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interrupt your thread in **onStop** method for all your activities. But its not a sophisticated way of doing things. There might be some other solutions, like defining a custom class which extends android's **Application** class and set your desired logic in that class with static methods, etc.

Comment: i get a null poit exception if i handle the thread form activities other than loginActivity

Comment: yes, because you dont have hold of thread in other activities. I think you should really go for extending *Application* class solution.

Comment: im doing that currently, but in the application class i dont have any method that lets me "check" the state of my app and therefore interrupt the thread. there is no onDestroy(), onSomething() method for application. how would i doo it?

Comment: why dont you define your own static boolean flag in that class and set that flag to lets say True in all of your activity's onStart method and False in onStop, and make your thread to read that flag value at each cycle to judge for killing it self. In fact you dont even need to have an Application class for this. Just use a public static field in any of your class

Comment: mmm nice idea, except would'nt the thread still be working in the background using a small amount of resources? because the thread would really stop only when you open again the app?

Comment: if you code correctly, then the thread will be killed automatically once it sees the flag value as False... its all up to you, how you code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop an individual thread yourThread.stop() should work. Otherwise use the answer by Estragon.

Comment: Thread.stop() has been depretiated. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()

Answer (score -3):

It's evil, but did u try

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

in the onDestroy of your last activity?

Otherwise, as estragon said, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle will be the right way to use activities

Comment: thing is, one could close the app on any activity